# Reactjs - setState doesn't re-render after update

Tags: node.js, reactjs, redux

Simply all i'm trying to do is re render the notes list when i add another note to the database. i tried several methods even redux `dispatch` method. but none worked and it kinda make sense because when i add a note i don't add anything so it can get the updated notes through `/budget`. maybe i have a big misunderstanding.

here's how i add a new note

```
export function saveOneNote() {
  // saving a note

  const _id = $('input[name="_id"]').val(),
    firstItem = $('input[name="firstItem"]').val(),
    firstPrice = $('input[name="firstPrice"]').val(),
    secondItem = $('input[name="secondItem"]').val(),
    secondPrice = $('input[name="secondPrice"]').val(),
    thirdItem = $('input[name="thirdItem"]').val(),
    thirdPrice = $('input[name="thirdPrice"]').val(),
    tBudget = $('input[name="tBudget"]').val();

  let currency = $("#currency").val();
  console.log(currency);
  $.ajax({
    url: "/newNote",
    type: "post",
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: "application/json",
    data: JSON.stringify({
      currency,
      _id,
      firstItem,
      firstPrice,
      secondItem,
      secondPrice,
      thirdItem,
      thirdPrice,
      tBudget
    }),
    success: function(Data) {
      console.log("note was saved!", Data);
    },
    error: function(err, status, xhr) {
      console.log("err", err);
    }
  });
}
```

here's how i fetch notes

```
 class ShowAll extends Component {
    constructor(props){
      super(props);

        this.state = {
          Data: [],
          length:[],
          searchbyid:[],
          isLoggedIn:[]
        }
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        // fetch notes

        Rquest.get('/budget').then((res)=>{
          let DataString = Array.from(res.body);

          this.setState((prevState,props)=>{
              return {
                Data: DataString,
                length: res.body.length
            }
          })
        }).catch((err)=> {
          console.log(err);
        })

          // check if user is logged in
          Request.get('/auth').then((user)=>{
            if(user){
                this.setState({
                    isLoggedIn: true
                })
            }
          }).catch((err)=> {
              this.setState({
                  isLoggedIn: false
              })
          });
        }
        render(){
          const count = this.state.length;
          const myNotes = this.state.Data;
          const isLoggedIn = this.state.isLoggedIn;
          const listItems = myNotes.map((dynamicData)=>{
          return(
            <Fragment key={dynamicData.id}>
            <div className='jumbotron'>
              <div className='row'>
              <button className='btn btn-danger delete-note-btn' onClick={DeleteOneNote}>Delete</button>
                <input className='col-12 title form-control' id='deleteById' value={dynamicData._id} readOnly/>
                <div className="dropdown-divider"></div> {/*line divider*/}
                  <div className='col-6' >
                    <ul className='list-unstyled'>
                      <li className='items'>items</li>
                      <li >{dynamicData.firstItem}</li>
                      <li >{dynamicData.secondItem}</li>
                      <li >{dynamicData.thirdItem}</li>
                      {/* <li>Total Budget :</li> */}
                    </ul>
                  </div>

                  <div className='dynamicData col-6'>
                    <ul className ='list-unstyled'>
                      <li className='prices'>Prices</li>
                      <li>{dynamicData.firstPrice} {dynamicData.currency}</li>
                      <li>{dynamicData.secondPrice} {dynamicData.currency}</li>
                      <li>{dynamicData.thirdPrice} {dynamicData.currency}</li>
                    </ul>
                  </div>
                    </div>
                    <h3 className='col-12 totalprice'>{dynamicData.tBudget} {dynamicData.currency}</h3>
                  </div>
            </Fragment>
            )
      })
        return (
          <Fragment>
              {isLoggedIn ===true?(
                <div className='myNotesList '>
                number of notes :  {count}
                {listItems}
                </div>
            ):(
              <Fragment>
                </Fragment>
            )
              }
          </Fragment>
          )
      }
  }
```

Comment: Do you see the data if you `console.log(DataString)` in componentDidMount?

Comment: It doesn't look like there's actually anything being returned from `render()`. Is there a part of it you left out? If so, include that

Comment: There's certainly data from `console.log(DataString)` it does work but it doesnt re render when it gets updated.

Comment: i edited the post. i just wanted it to be shorter as you dont need all of this.

Comment: Well, where are you calling the `saveOneNote` function, is it in another component?

Comment: Yes it is. I thought of calling the `Request.get('/budget')` function again after i save a note. But its out of scope for the `saveNote` as if i export it to another component i need to get it out and be a global function but then `this` is not defined. And i think its bad practice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

React components are re-rendering **only** on `state` or `props` change. In your code - you're **not** mutating `state` nor `props` of your component.

What you should do in your case probably is to re-fetch the items after `save` **or** add the new items to the `state` or pass through `props`.

Example:

```js
class Notes extends React.Component {
  state = { note: '', notes: [] }
  
  changeNote = ({ target: { value } }) => {
    this.setState({ note: value });
  }
  
  addNote = () => {
    this.setState((state) => ({ notes: [...state.notes, state.note] }));
  }
  
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <input type="text" onChange={this.changeNote} />
        <button onClick={this.addNote}>Add</button>
        <ul>
        {this.state.notes.map(note =>
          <li>{note}</li>
        )}
        </ul>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Notes />,
  document.getElementById('app')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.2.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.2.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">

</div>
```

Comment: Can you give an example on how to new items to `state`